# Variable is not defined on Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I'm trying to setup broadcast just like [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#concept-overview). I'm using pusher.

Here is my FriendRequestSent event:

```
class FriendRequestSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('friend-request.' . $this->id);
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
event(new FriendRequestSent("5a22f7e72e069a2e64001ed5"));
```

Here is my channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('friend-request.{receiverId}', function ($user, $receiverId) {
    return true;
});
```

and this is my script on the page:

```
<script>
    Echo.private(`friend-request.${receiverId}`)
    .listen('FriendRequestSent', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
</script>
```

Just like documentation. But I get this error in browser's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: receiverId is not defined.
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: where are you placing that <script> tag ? we need to know how you have imported the scripts and where you declared `receiverId` in your javascript

Comment: Helpfull maybe: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/158